# How do i optimise a Python loop parallelize/multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have to loop for N times to calculate formulas and add results in dataframe.
My code works and takes a few seconds to process each Item. However, it can only do one item at a time because I'm running the array through a for loop:

I try to update Code and I add  numba library to optimise code

```
def calculationResults(myconfig,df_results,isvalid,dimension,....othersparams):
    for month in nb.prange(0, myconfig.len_production):   
        calculationbymonth(month,df_results,,....othersparams)
    return df_results
```

But it's still doing one item at a time?
ANy Ideas?

Comment: We need more code to be able to understand what you're doing. I don't see any threading or multiprocessing being applied here.

Answer (score 1):

We can use parallelized apply using the similar to below function.

```
def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_cores=4):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df
```

Comment: I don't undestand your answer I have a function to calculate iteration for or N item and a second function to calculate each Item) If i need to improve perfermence with a Multiprocessing Pool to loop for many item in the same time I have a function with many arguments

def calculationResults(myconfig,df_results,isvalid,dimension,....othersparams):
    for month in nb.prange(0, myconfig.len_production):   
        calculationbymonth(month,df_results,,....othersparams)
    return df_results
in wich function i need to add Multiprocessing Pool in the first function or in the second one?